# Create a from builder using Django

Tags: reactjs, django, django-forms, drag-and-drop, google-forms

I am fairly new to programming and start my career with Python Django. I already build some basic application and recently came across to use google forms and decided to create application like this.
Where any user can come to certain page and can able to create his own form as per his requirement.

I though of some new features like drag and drop. I wanted to ask if that's somehow possible to drag drop input fields or something like that using Django template system where I can use some simple JS library or if its possible using React as fronted.
So my requirements are quite simple, but I am confused with Django models that what will be the structure of models.

1. UI should be drag n drop thing. User can select the list of fields available in the inventory. And create his own form.

And on post submission. From django you need to capture and store the data.

Here in this case the data will be the form fields as well as its values.

Ex form fields which are available in the inventory.

1. Test field
2. Email Field
3. Multi select field and
4. Drop Down Field=

I hope someone can help me so that I can get started and came up with some methodology.

Comment: Welcome Jack. Fairly vague far reaching question here. You may find better help when you narrow things down. Django can do all of what you state. Drag and drop would use a javascript library with Django on the back end.

Comment: Hi Jack, did you come across any solution for your requirement?